# android camera mobile application development with actionscript 3.0 and Animate CC and AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, android-camera, orientation, screen-rotation, adobe-animate

I am new in coding and especially in ActionScript 3.0 and Adobe Animate.

I am trying to develop, for practice, for android smartphones, a simple camera application to shoot and save photographs.

The main issue is the correct landscape-portrait orientation of the "photo-container" on the screen of the mobile phone.
So, while rotating the smartphone (portrait-landscape) the "photo-container" disappears from the smartphone screen. Obviously x and y properties go out of the screen.
I have tried a lot of different approaches but I am missing something :(

Is there somewhere a clear solution that I could study so as to understand what I am doing wrong?
e.g. a sample code to study for "reverse-engineering" purposes to help me understand how camera orientation works?

(Another big issue is "permissions" but, anyway, I do not dare to start with this before I understand how the orientation works...)

I am very frustrated and disappointed and I do not know what to do because it looks like there are not a lot of resources about ActionScript 3.0 on the web and when I find something, it is really outdated!

Thank you very much for every type of help or guidance.

P.S.: it looks like there is, natively, a bug in AIR because the default orientation of the image, on the screen, while in portrait/side-up position is rotated 90 degrees anticlockwise (!)

Here is my code, so far:

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAspectRatio;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.GestureEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.media.CameraRoll;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.sensors.Geolocation;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

  //basic UI
var headerr:MovieClip;
var footerr:MovieClip;
var backgroundd:MovieClip;
var consolee:TextField;
var consoleFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var photoContainer:MovieClip;


stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

//////////////////// START //////////////////////////

var camera:Camera;
var video:Video;

var cameraBitmapData:BitmapData;
var cameraBitmap:Bitmap;

function setCamera():void {
    camera = Camera.getCamera();
    camera.setMode(800, 600, 24); // background.width, background.height
    video = new Video(800, 600);  // background.width, background.height
    cameraBitmapData = new BitmapData(800, 600, false, 0xFFFFFF);
  cameraBitmap = new Bitmap(cameraBitmapData); 
  video.attachCamera(camera);
  photoContainer.addChild(cameraBitmap);
  stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

function loop(e:Event):void {
  if (video && cameraBitmapData) {
  cameraBitmapData.draw(video, null, null, null, null, true)};
}

//-----------------------------------------------------

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        //tap anywhere on STAGE to shoot & save an image
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, saveImage);


function saveImage(event:TouchEvent):void {
    var capture = new BitmapData(background.width, background.height);
    capture.draw(video);

    var cameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
    cameraRoll.addBitmapData(capture);
}


///////////////////// END///////////////////////////////////////


this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, adjustAppLayout);

function adjustAppLayout(e:Event):void {
    header.width = stage.stageWidth;
    header.height = stage.stageHeight*0.10;

    footer.width = stage.stageWidth;
    footer.height = stage.stageHeight*0.02;
    footer.y = stage.stageHeight-footer.height;

    background.width = stage.stageWidth;
    background.height = stage.stageHeight-footer.height-header.height;
    background.y = header.height;

    consoleFormat.size = stage.stageHeight*0.03;
    console.defaultTextFormat = consoleFormat;
    console.width = stage.stageWidth;
    console.height = background.height - 20;
    console.y = header.height + 10;


    photoContainer.scaleX = 1;
    photoContainer.scaleY = 1;
    photoContainer.y = header.height;   
    photoContainer.x = 0; //<--------- header.width


setCamera();
}



stage.autoOrients = true;

stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, onChange);

function onChange(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
    console.appendText(event.afterOrientation + "\n");

/*  
  if (event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.DEFAULT) {
   photoContainer.rotation=90;
   photoContainer.x=800;
   photoContainer.y=0;
  } else if (event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT) {
   photoContainer.rotation=0;
   photoContainer.x=0;
   photoContainer.y=0;
  } else if (event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT) {
   photoContainer.rotation=-90;
   photoContainer.x=0;
   photoContainer.y=600;
  }

*/  

    switch (event.afterOrientation) { 
        case StageOrientation.DEFAULT: 
            // re-orient display objects based on the default/correct-side-up orientation.
            photoContainer.rotation = 90;
            //photoContainer.scaleX = 1;
            //photoContainer.scaleY = 1;
            photoContainer.x = header.width;
            photoContainer.y = header.height;   
            break; 
        case StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT: 
            // Re-orient display objects based on right-hand orientation. 
            photoContainer.rotation = 360;
            //photoContainer.scaleX = 1;
            //photoContainer.scaleY = 1;
            photoContainer.x = 0;
            photoContainer.y = console.height;  
            break; 
        case StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT: 
            // Re-orient display objects based on left-hand orientation. 
            photoContainer.rotation = 0;
            //photoContainer.scaleX = 1;
            //photoContainer.scaleY = 1;
            photoContainer.x = 0;
            photoContainer.y = console.height;  
            break; 

    /*  
        case StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN: 
            // Re-orient display objects based on upside-down orientation. 
            photoContainer.rotation = 360;
            photoContainer.scaleX = 1;
            photoContainer.scaleY = 1;
            photoContainer.x = console.width;
            photoContainer.y = console.height + 10; 
            break; 
    */  

    }

}
```

**An updated code follows** (includes a shutter button for the camera, a geolocation function with the relevant button, too and some feedback of the sensors on a *console* on the screen)  with a little bit better result but still far from perfect, regarding the photoContainer rotation/orientation on the smartphone-screen:

```js
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAspectRatio;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.GestureEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.media.CameraRoll;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.sensors.Geolocation;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var headerr:MovieClip;
var footerr:MovieClip;
var backgroundd:MovieClip;
var consolee:TextField;
var consoleFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;

//=====================================================

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

//////////////////// START //////////////////////////

var camera:Camera;
var video:Video;

var cameraBitmapData:BitmapData;
var cameraBitmap:Bitmap;

function setCamera():void {
    camera = Camera.getCamera();
    camera.setMode(800,600, 24); 
    video = new Video(800, 600); 
    cameraBitmapData = new BitmapData(800, 600, false, 0xFFFFFF);
  cameraBitmap = new Bitmap(cameraBitmapData); 
  video.attachCamera(camera);
  photoContainer.addChild(cameraBitmap);
  stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

function loop(e:Event):void {
  if (video && cameraBitmapData) {
  cameraBitmapData.draw(video, null, null, null, null, true)};
}

//-----------------------------------------------------

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;


        ////tapping on shutter button

shutter_btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, interaction_feedback);

            //dim button
function interaction_feedback(event:TouchEvent):void {
    shutter_btn.alpha -=0.5;
}

            //shoot & save an image 
shutter_btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, saveImage);

function saveImage(event:TouchEvent):void {
    var capture = new BitmapData(800, 600); //background.width, background.height  same?
    capture.draw(video);

    var cameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
    cameraRoll.addBitmapData(capture);
}

        //light-back button
shutter_btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, interaction_feedbackEnd);

function interaction_feedbackEnd(event:TouchEvent):void {
    shutter_btn.alpha = 1;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------


    ///// GPS
if(Geolocation.isSupported){
    var geoloc = new Geolocation();
    geoloc.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onUpdate);
}

function onUpdate(e:GeolocationEvent):void {

    console.appendText("latitude: " + e.latitude + "\n");
    console.appendText("longitude: " + e.longitude + "\n");
    console.appendText("altitude: " + e.altitude + "\n");
    console.appendText("horizontal accuracy: " + e.horizontalAccuracy + "\n");
    console.appendText("vertical accuracy: " + e.verticalAccuracy + "\n");
    console.appendText("heading: " + e.heading + "\n");
    console.appendText("speed: " + e.speed + "\n");
    console.appendText("timestamp: " + e.timestamp + "\n");

    geoloc.removeEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onUpdate);

    var longitude = e.longitude;
    var latitude = e.latitude;


nav_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navClick);

var navigate:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + String(latitude) + ", " + String(longitude) );

function navClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(navigate);
    }   
}

///////////////////// END///////////////////////////////////////


this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, adjustAppLayout);

function adjustAppLayout(e:Event):void {
    header.width = stage.stageWidth;
    header.height = stage.stageHeight*0.10;

    footer.width = stage.stageWidth;
    footer.height = stage.stageHeight*0.02;
    footer.y = stage.stageHeight-footer.height;

    background.width = stage.stageWidth;
    background.height = stage.stageHeight-footer.height-header.height;
    background.y = header.height;

    consoleFormat.size = stage.stageHeight*0.03;
    console.defaultTextFormat = consoleFormat;
    console.width = stage.stageWidth;
    console.height = background.height - 20;
    console.y = header.height + 10;

    shutter_btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    shutter_btn.y = stage.stageHeight-footer.height-75;
    nav_btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    nav_btn.y = stage.stageHeight-background.height-50;

    photoContainer.scaleX = 1;
    photoContainer.scaleY = 1;
    photoContainer.y = header.height;   
}


stage.autoOrients = true;

stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, onChange);


setCamera();


function onChange(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
    console.appendText(event.afterOrientation + "\n");


  if (event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.DEFAULT) {
   photoContainer.rotation=90; 
   photoContainer.x = photoContainer.width;
   photoContainer.y = photoContainer.height;
  } else if (event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT) {
   photoContainer.rotation=0;
   photoContainer.x=0;
   photoContainer.y=0;
  } else if (event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT) {
   photoContainer.rotation=0;
   photoContainer.x=0;
   photoContainer.y=0;
  }
}


//myChecks
console.appendText("screenDPI: " + Capabilities.screenDPI + "\n");
console.appendText("screenResolutionX: " + Capabilities.screenResolutionX + "\n");
console.appendText("screenResolutionY: " + Capabilities.screenResolutionY + "\n");

console.appendText("Camera: " + Camera.isSupported + "\n");
console.appendText("CameraUI: " + CameraUI.isSupported + "\n");
console.appendText("Microphone: " + Microphone.isSupported + "\n");
```

A brainstorming is welcome! 
Thanks